# How to use putty to run a .sas program via a .bat file

Tags: sas

I'm using two files:
1- .bat file which contains in one line:

```
"C:\Path_to\putty.exe" -ssh servername -l myuserid -pw my password -m "C:\Path_to_Commands_File\Commands.txt" -t
```

2- Commands.txt which contains either one of these commands:
Command#1:

```
/Path_to_sasprogram/sasprogram.sas
```

OR

Commands#2 in the following order:

```
cd /Path_to_sasprogram/
sas sasprogram.sas
```

However, the sasprogram.sas does not get executed. So, I used putty to manually execute the commands above. With the commands#2, I get this error: "sas: command not found".
Any suggestions/help  would be greatly appreciated! BTW, I tried some solutions already posted, but they didn't work for me. Thanks

Comment: To execute the sasprogram, I run the .bat file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like sas is not on the path of your session.

try

```
/path_to_sas_executable/sas sasprogram.sas
```

Comment: The /path_to_sas_executable on the server?